# international date formatting fails

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying with a child of DateTime to extend the functionality of DateTime for international formatting and simple database formatting. But it does not work with negative Date. `var_dump` of my Date object shows me the following:

```
object(Date)[98]
  public 'date' => string '-0001-11-30 00:00:00' (length=20)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

`$this->format('Y-m-d')` works fine, but not with `IntlDateFormatter`.
This is my Code:

```
class Date extends DateTime
{

    public function __toString()
    {
        $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(Locale::getDefault(), IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM);

        return $fmt->format($this);
    }

    public function toSqlDate()
    {
        return new String($this->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }
}
```

Edit: It´s `new Date('0000-00-00')` which causes the fail.

Comment: How exactly does it "fail"?

Comment: with a white page / no output anymore after this